# PHP Concatenation to echo script inside of a ternary

Tags: php, ternary

I've just started using ternary operators as I feel they really do make my code look neater - however today I've encountered a problem.

I am trying to echo some script tags into my header if a certain request variable is set to true (to reduce http requests for un-needed files), however whenever I try to load my page I get an error:

```
require_once(./public/lib/functions.js'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;):
```

^ in the above section, why is the browser interpreting the html encoded character, and why do I lose the `<script>` tag which precedes my require statement?

Here is the code I am using.

```
echo $ajax_required == true 
  ? "<script src='" . require_once(LIBRADIR . 'functions.js') . "'></script>" 
  : false;
```

Thanks in advance,
Alex.

Comment: Looks to me like you don't really know what `require_once` does. Including a JavaScript file into a PHP file most likely isn't what you want to do. And please don't start using the ternary operator for complex statements. That's awful code quality.

Comment: What's the purpose of `html_entity_decode(($ajax_required == true)) `???

Comment: I think the use of ternary operators for statements being untidy is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its just a `.js` file and not a `.php` file, then you might have used directly file name as a string, instead `require()`.

```
echo html_entity_decode(($ajax_required == true)) 
  ? "<script src='" . LIBRADIR . "functions.js'></script>" 
  : false;
```

*Note:* [require()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.require.php) is used to include a `.php` script inside code, mostly to just re-use your existing code (functions, classes etc).

Comment: yep you're completely right - completely overlooked the require statement, thank-you

Answer (score 2):

Currently it is evaluated as:

```
require_once(('index.php'). "'></script>")
```

You just need another parenthesis for higher precedence:

```
(require_once('index.php'))
^                         ^
```

```
echo html_entity_decode((true == true)) 
  ? "<script src='" . (require_once('index.php')) . "'></script>" 
  : false;
```

[Example on the Doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-157)

Also remember `require_once` or `require` are language construct you don't need to call them as function arguments. You can also write the above statement like this:

```
(require_once 'index.php')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely no use of require_once as it is used for PHP files. I think you simply want to do this:

```
echo $ajax_required? "<script src='" . LIBRADIR . "functions.js'></script>": "";
```

This will just print the output that comes from the ternary operator i.e. either the script tag or empty string.

Comment: Yep thats exactly what I wanted to do, completely overlooked that I'd put reqire_once in the statement, careless on my behalf - I'll make sure I read back my code a few more times before I post.

Comment: Yes, that happens in coding. I would say you can use ternary operators in specific requirements like these where based on a simple condition you just want to echo or use some value. If your $ajax_required variable has either true or false, you can avoid the == check as well and just use the value for test as I did in my code.

Comment: Thanks again Nitigya :), will tidy that portion of my code now!